# How to trigger IsMouseOver on existing tabcontrol?

Tags: c#, wpf, triggers, tabcontrol, ismouseover

How can I trigger the `IsMouseOver` property in an existing WPF TabControl?
I tried making a Style but it only creates a new Tab. I want to apply it on the tabs I've already made.What basically i wanna do is to edit the background of the header when the mouse is located over it.

Is there a way to do it? Maybe through c#?

```html
<TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="100">
  <TabItem Header="AddItem">
    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" />
  </TabItem>
  <TabItem Header="UpdateItem">
    <Grid Background="#FFE5E5E5" />
  </TabItem>
</TabControl>
```

Comment: Do you want to know when the mouse pointer is located over your tabcontrol?

Comment: i want to edit/change the color of the header background when the mouse pointer is located  over the header of one of the tabs.

Comment: Do you mean to change just  the background color of the header where the mouse is over or the background of _all_ the headers?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `MouseMove` event and then check the mouse.X and mouse.Y position. Then get the tabcontrol header location and compare it with the mouse position.

Comment: I edited my question: I want to edit/change the color of the header background when the mouse pointer is located over the header of one of the tabs.